# I was able to solve addNum(4,5) and addNum(4)(5) in interview, but what if addNum(1)(2)...(N)?

Tags: javascript, closures

Yesterday I attended an interview on JavaScript,

they asked me a question,
write a program for following,

```
addNum(4,5);
addNum(4)(5);
```

I wrote it. It is as Follows

```
 var fn18 = function(){
    var addNum = function(){
        var argLength = arguments.length,
            num = 0;            
        if(argLength > 1){
            for(var x=0;x < argLength; x++){
                num += parseInt(arguments[x],10);
            }

            return num;
        }else if(argLength == 1){
            num = arguments[0];

            var fn = function (param){                  
                var n = num + param;
                return n;
            }   

            return fn;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    };

    print("1> addNum(2,4) => "+addNum(2,4)+"\n");   
    print("2> addNum(2)(5) => "+addNum(2)(5)+"\n");
    print("3> addNum() => "+addNum()+"\n");
};

fn18();
```

The above program works fine.
Please ignore the "print" keyword as I am running this on Rhino library on java.

So my question is how should be my approach to solve this

```
addNum(2)(3)(4).....(N)
```

I tired with returning function recursively, but it prints the whole function.

What should be my approach ?

Comment: Technically, you can't do that; you cannot curry a variadic function. You need to tell somehow that it is the last argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this (omitting the solution for the first case, `addNum(4,5)`):

```
function addNum(num) {
    var fun = function(num2) {
        fun.sum += num2;
        return fun;
    }
    fun.sum = num;  
    return fun;
}
```

You can chain as many you want, and at any time call `.sum` on the returned function and get the current sum.